# Page jumps to top screen because of getOwnerComponent setModel

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have a list of checkbox in a two tabs page, the problem I have is the page jumps to topscreen when I click on a checkbox in the first tab and this code gets called :

```
this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(mymodel,"mymodel")
```

If I navigate between the tabs and go back it doesn't happen anymore, this only happens when i click checkbox before navigating.

My checkbox :

```
<CheckBox app:mydata="a" select="onSelect" ></CheckBox>
```

N.B : this only happens if i'm trying to overwrites a model I created in Component.js (mymodel). If I set another model to the componentowner using another name it works fine

Comment: I don't really see a question, but the behaviour seems valid. If you call `setProperty` on a model and the framework detects that the new value is indeed new it will trigger a rerender. I guess that something similar happens here: You overwrite a model (which is essentially new data) and the framework thinks it has to rerender the whole page because the original data changed.

Comment: @Marc But why that isn't happening when I navigate to another tab and go back and do the exact same thing (ovewriting the model)

Comment: Don't know, but I don't see the what's the point in overwriting a whole model in the first place.

Comment: I thought about this. After you overwrite the model, go to another tab and then go back and overwrite the model again, the data probably hasn't changed. So the second time `setModel` gets called the old model and the new model contain (probably) the same data. No change > no need to rerender.

Comment: @Marc no i'm changing the data in the model in both tabs and it only jumps topscreen the first time. Weird!